# draw a complex shape with "for each"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce the following shapes:

[image]

But it doesn't work well:

[image]

I'm trying to increment coordinate but it doesn't seem to work

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

\usepackage{tikz}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre

%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)

\usepackage{xcolor}


\newdimen\R
\R=3cm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large},thick, line cap=round, line width=0.4mm, line join=round, >=latex, x=1cm, y=1cm]


%\pic[fill=orange!20]{squaroid={width=4, height=4}};
\draw[] (0:\R) \foreach \x in {0,180,...,359}{
            --(\x:\R)
            --++(135+\x:{2*\R/5})
            arc (-45+\x:45+\x:\R/5-\R/60)
            arc (45+\x:135+\x:\R/5-\R*2/60)
            arc (135+\x:225+\x:\R/5-\R*3/60)
            arc (225+\x:315+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (315+\x:225+\x:\R/5-\R*5/60)
            arc (225+\x:135+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (135+\x:45+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (45+\x:-45+\x:\R/5-\R*3/60)
            arc (-45+\x:-225+\x:\R/5)
            --++(135+\x:{2*\R/5})
            --++(270+\x:{2*\R/5})
            arc (45+\x:-135+\x:\R/5)
            arc (-135+\x:-225+\x:\R/5-\R*3/60)
            arc (-225+\x:-315+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (-315+\x:-405+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (-405+\x:-495+\x:\R/5-\R*5/60)
            arc (-495+\x:-405+\x:\R/5-\R*4/60)
            arc (-405+\x:-315+\x:\R/5-\R*3/60)
            arc (-315+\x:-225+\x:\R/5-\R*2/60)
            arc (-225+\x:-135+\x:\R/5-\R*1/60)
            --+(-135+\x:{2*\R/5})
        } -- cycle 
        %(72:\R) node[above] {$n=5$} 
        ;
%\draw[-, opacity=0.8, samples=200, domain=-4:4, orange]
%    plot(\x,-1) coordinate node [label=a] {}
%    ;
%\draw[-, opacity=0.8, samples=200, domain=-4:4, blue]
%    plot(0,\x) coordinate node [label={[left, inner sep=6pt]b}] {}
%    ;
%\draw[-, opacity=0.8, samples=200, domain=-4:4, purple]
%    plot(\x,0) coordinate node [label=c] {}
%    ;
%\draw[-, opacity=0.8, samples=200, domain=-3:3, green]
%    plot(\x,\x) coordinate node [label=d] {}
%    ;
%\draw[]
%    (0,0) coordinate node[circle, fill=orange, draw=black, scale=.5, label={[above left, inner sep=6pt]O}] {}
%    (0,-1) coordinate node[circle, fill=orange, draw=black, scale=.5, label={[below right, inner sep=6pt]P}] {};
%draw the main coordinate system axes
%\pic at (0,0,0) {calcross};

%end
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question about the foreach loop literally, one could post

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{3}
\draw (0:\R) \foreach \X in {0,...,3}{
            --(\X*90:\R)
            -- ++ (135+\X*90:{\R/2})
            foreach \Y in {1,...,5}
            {arc[start angle=-135+\Y*90+\X*90,end angle=-45+\Y*90+\X*90,
                radius=\R/5-\Y*\R/60]}
            arc[start angle=-135+6*90+\X*90,end angle=-45+7*90+\X*90,
                radius=\R/60]   
            foreach \Y in {5,...,0}
            {arc[start angle=-45+\Y*90+\X*90,end angle=-135+\Y*90+\X*90,
                radius=\R/5-\Y*\R/60-\R/30]}
            arc[start angle=-135+\X*90,end angle=-225+\X*90,
                radius=\R/5-\R/60]              
        } -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for repeating tasks like this I prefer to use `pic`s. This is in particular the case if you want to highlight some reflection symmetries because these pics can be transformed. That is, in order to have something that respects some Euclidean transformations, you just need to act on this with these transformations until you reach the original object. This here is the conjugacy class of the group element "rotation by 90 followed by reflection about the y axis", i.e. a Z_4 subgroup of the Euclidean group.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/spiral/.style={code={
 \tikzset{spiral/.cd,#1}
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiral/##1}}
  \draw (0:{\pv{R}}) coordinate (-a) --
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:\pv{tmax},samples=61,smooth]
    (\t:{\pv{r}-\pv{r}*abs(\t/\pv{trel})})
    -- ++({abs(\pv{tmax})+90}:1pt) \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myan}{abs(\pv{tmax})+90}}
    to[out=\myan,in=\myan]
   (\pv{tmax}:{\pv{r}+\pv{dr}-\pv{r}*abs(\pv{tmax}/\pv{trel})}) --
   plot[variable=\t,domain=\pv{tmax}:-180,samples=61,smooth]
   (\t:{\pv{r}+\pv{dr}-\pv{r}*abs(\t/\pv{trel})})
   -- (-180:\pv{R}) coordinate (-b);
  }},
  spiral/.cd,tmax/.initial=-630,trel/.initial=450,dr/.initial=0.1,
  r/.initial=1,R/.initial=2]
 \begin{scope}[rotate=45,transform shape,line cap=rect,thick,
    spiral/.cd,r=0.6,trel=720,R=1.5]
  \path (90:1.5) pic{spiral} 
    (180:1.5) pic[rotate=90,xscale=-1]{spiral}
    (270:1.5) pic[rotate=180,scale=-1]{spiral}
    (0:1.5) pic[rotate=270,yscale=-1]{spiral};  
 \end{scope}
 \draw[red] (-90:3) -- (90:3) node[pos=1.05] {$\mathsf{a}$}
  (45:3) -- (-135:3) node[pos=1.05] {$\mathsf{c}$};
 \draw[green!60!black] (180:3) -- (0:3) node[pos=1.05] {$\mathsf{b}$}
  (-45:3) -- (135:3) node[pos=1.05] {$\mathsf{d}$};
 \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,label=below left:$O$] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx! i'm still trying to figure it out your second code.

Answer (score 5):

You draw dotted circles to guide you

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikz{
    \draw[dotted]
        (0,0)foreach\r in{1,3,...,9}{circle(\r)}
        (0,2)foreach\r in{1,3,...,9}{circle(\r)};
    \draw[red]
        foreach\r in{1,3,...,9}{(0,-\r)arc(-90:90:\r)}
        foreach\r in{1,3,...,9}{(0,\r+2)arc(90:270:\r)}
    ;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer